# Method local variables and stack and heap

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, heap-memory, stack-memory

While reading on Thread Safety I came across this issue. 
If I'm correct method local Primitives and object references lives inside a stack and actual objects pointed by the references inside the stack lives in the heap.

But when it comes to method local non primitive object initialization, wouldn't that cause a concurrency issue ? I mean if the method locals non primitives lives in the heap and only the pointers lives in the stacks, isn't it the same as of instance variables ?

Can someone please help me to understand this....

PS

Think of two threads with each having two stacks of their own and one heap. What I understood is that the two threads keep their method local primitive variables inside their stacks. I have no issue with that.

But what if we have a method with non primitive method local variables ? Then if the object for that variable is stored inside the heap, both the threads will have the access to the same object, won't they ? So if that's the case there would be Sync problems.

That is what I'm asking.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of concurrency issue are you envisioning?

Comment: Nothing specific. Just want to know how threads handle non primitive objects if I'm correct in the above question.

Comment: I don't see how threads are relevant to this at all. You're not being very clear about your concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both threads could have access to the same object if they both have a reference to the object. If you have a method like the following:

```
public String concat(String a, String b) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(a);
    builder.append(b);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

The StringBuilder object is indeed in the heap, but only one thread has a reference to this object. No other thread can have a reference to this StringBuilder. So it's inherently thread-safe.

If, on the contrary, you have the following:

```
public String concat(String a, String b) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            builder.append("haha!");
        }
    }).start();
    builder.append(a);
    builder.append(b);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Then you have a thread-safety issue, because you shere the locally created object reference with another thread, and StringBuilder is not thread-safe.

Comment: Referring the first part of the code snippet, did you mean that there'll be multiple copies of **builder** objects in the heap ? (one for each thread)

Comment: Yes, of course. When you do `new SomeObject()`, you create a **new** instance of `SomeObject`.

Comment: Thanks and again why not keeping the method local non primitives inside the stack ?

Comment: @PrasadWeera: The same object can be referenced by several variables, some local to methods, some being instance or static fields.

Comment: While everything stated is somewhat correct, this response only incidentally talks to the question asked.  As well, the discussion that follows strongly suggests (to what appears to be a beginner) that the distinction is *thread* uniqueness ("Yes, of course..").  That suggests that the same method called twice on the same thread might share the builder - and that's clearly not correct.  There are better responses to this query.

Comment: The question was about thread safety for objects, which are stored in the heap. My answer answers this question, which appeared, later, thanks to the comments, to come from a misunderstanding of what new does. My answer "Yes of course" answers the question "did you mean that there'll be multiple copies of builder objects in the heap ? (one for each thread)". And indeed, each thread executing this code will create a new instance in the heap, as the following explains: "When you do new SomeObject(), you create a new instance of SomeObject". Every word counts. Not just the 3 first ones.

Answer (score 3):

> But what if we have a method with non primitive method local variables
>   ? Then if the object for that variable is stored inside the heap, both
>   the threads will have the access to the same object, won't they ? So
>   if that's the case there would be Sync problems.

I wonder why you will think the two references will refer to the same object.

The creation of the object referred is explicitly done by new (or other similar method, but idea is the same)

Therefore, unlike in C++, if you are declaring this in Java

```
Foo foo;
```

there is no Foo object instantiated.  `foo` is just a pointer pointing to nothing.

This will create you a Foo object instance in heap.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

If two thread is running this piece of code, thread 1 will have a `Foo` reference in stack, and ask to allocate a new `Foo` object in heap, and then assign the address of that `Foo` obj to the reference `foo`.  Thread 2 is doing the same.  Note that Thread 2 is also asking to allocate a new `Foo` object, it will be a different object from what Thread 1 is allocated.

That's the basic (and much simplified) idea.

Answer (score 1):

`But what if we have a method with non primitive method local variables ? Then if the object for that variable is stored inside the heap, both the threads will have the access to the same object, won't they ? So if that's the case there would be Sync problems`

You partially answered your own question.That reference value is stored in the stack but the actual object content is stored in heap and when you call new Object() each thread creates different new object that will be stored in the heap and each thread access the object it has created using the reference value stored in its own stack

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are either primitives, references to objects created somewhere else (if you do an assignation), or references to newly created objects (using "new" operator)

For the first case, as you said, there is no issue.

For the last case, as you are locally craeting a new object, a new object will be created at every call, so no concurrency issue because there will be one object in the heap for each call

But for the second case, as the object has been created somewhere else, you have to think about concurrency

Answer (score 0):

Just to toss in my thoughts regarding what may be your point of confusion: the heap is not managed like the stack.  It is shared, yes - in that objects created by all threads are in the heap.  However as each object is *created*, it's given a unique location/space in the heap.  Two methods on two threads running concurrently and creating an object instance will create distinctly different objects in the shared heap.

They're created in this shared heap so that if method `foo` returns the object reference, or stores it, or calls another method that indirectly stores it... it won't be destroyed when `foo` returns and the stack is popped.

The magic of having a garbage collector is that you don't have to keep track of this "stuff" and destroy it yourself at some appropriate point in the future.  Keeps your code simple, lets you focus on algorithms (or learning to program).  But I digress...